# k8s - multiple ownerrefs in CRDs

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-custom-resources, merge-strategy

Say I have the following CRD:

```
...
kind: SomeCRD
metadata:
  ownerReferences:
  - uid: aaa
    name: name-a
...
```

When I run `kubectl apply -f some.yaml` where some.yaml is the following

```
...
kind: SomeCRD
metadata:
  ownerReferences:
  - uid: bbb
    name: name-b
...
```

I'd like to have the ownerrefs merged as the following:

```
...
kind: SomeCRD
metadata:
  ownerReferences:
  - uid: aaa
    name: name-a
  - uid: bbb
    name: name-b
...
```

Is that possible? Currently `kubectl apply` would simply replace the existing ownerReferences `aaa` with `bbb`, while it would merge the ownerReferences `aaa` and `bbb` for native types such as Pod.

If I understand it correctly, strategic merge isn't supported for CRDs by default, but starting from 1.16/1.17 we can define merge strategy in the schema of the CRDs ([k8s doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/server-side-apply/#merge-strategy)). Ideally we could define the merge strategy for `metadata.ownerReferences` in the schema of someCRD and that'd solve the problem here, but `metadata` belongs to apiserver and can't be redefined in CRDs. It feels like `metadata` is stuck in some unfortunate state where it's a k8s native type, but treated as an unstructured field when it's in CRDs.

Any way to make this work or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance! :)